# Ionic/AngularJS checkbox and ng-repeat from API

Tags: angularjs, api, checkbox, ionic-v1

The idea was to send true checkbox values from mobile to API so I can place an order with selected condiments, however I cant to get a grasp on it. Condiments are returned from HTTP GET call to API.

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="condiment in condiments" ng-model="condiment.checked"
                          ng-checked="checkItem(condiment.id)">
                {{condiment.name}}
                {{condiment.price}}
</ion-checkbox>
```

It calls the function:

```
$scope.checkItem = function (id) {
            return $scope.condiments[id-1].checked = true;
};
```

(minus 1 is because ID starts at 1, and array at 0)
But it is not called when checked/unchecked, but rather it makes all my resources checked by default, and once I click to uncheck them, nothing  changes.

Property 'checked' is not part of the original JSON API output for the condiment. It has ID, name and price.

**Question:**

Is there a less painful way to send checked ID's back to server?

**Edit:**

I tried to set the default variables before, but that does nothing:

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.condiments; i++){
            $scope.condiments[i].checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me also Faced this kind of issue, 
 I solved this by using like this,

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="condiment.checked" ng-true-value="1"
        ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="condiment.checked == 1">
```

This will Change your ng-checked `True`  directly in json.. so after that simply console your  `API "condiments"` you will get your answer..

and if you want set checked by default False .simply use , `ng-init="condiment.checked=0"`. so, if you checked it will return True else You will get False .

Comment: That works amazing! Thanks

Comment: Just one thing...it seems I have to click twice in order to change the value of the checkbox?

Comment: are you using ng-init and ng-checked in same line? if it means remove ng-init and place it somewhere or make it false in backend itself.. else tell me the exactly what happen? if u create fiddle its much better to identify your issue.

Comment: The documentation for `ng-checked` clearly states that using it with `ng-model` can produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the Angular Docs on checkboxes https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked. It clearly tells don't use `ng-model` with `ng-checked`, it may lead in unexpected results.

You can remove `ng-checked`...

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="condiment in condiments" ng-model="condiment.checked">
            {{condiment.name}}
            {{condiment.price}}
</ion-checkbox>
```

and in controller you can get condiments id's

```
$scope.checkItems = function(){
    var CID = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.condiments,function(condiment){
        if(condiment.checked){
           CID.push(condiment.id);
        }
    });

    //send CID to server
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, here is the fiddle created for you. [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/3265/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in condiments">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[val.id]" 
                   ng-click="checked(key,selected[val.id])"
                   ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">
              {{val.name}}
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>added status into main array
            <br>{{condiments}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the controller and logic

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.selected = {};
        $scope.condiments = [{ id: 1, name: "item1", price: 100 },
                             { id: 2, name: "item2", price: 200 },
                             { id: 3, name: "item3", price: 300 }];
        angular.forEach($scope.condiments, function(val, index) {
            $scope.selected[val.id] = "true";
            $scope.condiments[index].checked = true;
        })
        $scope.checked = function(key, status) {
            if (status == "true") {
                $scope.condiments[key].checked = true;
            } else {
                $scope.condiments[key].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```